# Error using the dropdown: The connection to the server has been lost

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, window, visual-studio-2022

I want to bind my comboBox through design but Visual Studio 2022 shows an error:

[image]

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Error using the dropdown: The connection to the server has been lost.

Comment: @marc_s I am looking for a solution not for  edition

Comment: If targeting .NET Core 5 or 6, try creating a .NET Framework 4.8 simple project and try the same task, reason for the ask is this issue may be with how internals in Visual Studio are handling Core projects and if so consider reporting the issue to Microsoft with the bug/feedback button in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Whenever you are creating your project Select **"Window Form App (.NET Framwork)"**. Then this error will never occure.

Reason:
ADO.NET Entity Data Model are come up with .NET Framwork so if we want ADO.NET Entity Data Model then we have to choose **"Window Form App (.NET Framwork)"**

[image]

**Solution 2:**
What if we have created our project without selecting **"Window Form App (.NET Framwork)"**.
Solution is to replace/add your App.config file with below code:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      
      
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UseWPF>False</UseWPF>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>

        <LangVersion>10</LangVersion>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
        <StartupObject></StartupObject>
        <PackAsTool>False</PackAsTool>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
        <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In above code we just selected the target framework .NET