# DataBinding Inaccessible in VS2022 with .NET 6 - Error using the dropdown: The connection to the server has been lost

Tags: c#, winforms

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73596050/error-using-the-dropdown-the-connection-to-the-server-has-been-lost) neatly sums up my problem, but the solution doesn't seem reasonable. Every solution I have seen to this problem tells people to just use Framework 4.8.

This seems absurd!  Framework 4.8 is locked to C# 7.3, while .NET 7 is up to C# 11.  We've been beyond Framework for YEARS. Surely there is a way to enable data binding for .NET 5+ in 2023.  I don't understand how such a vital part of application development as data binding for controls like ListBoxes, ComboBoxes, and DataGridViews can just NOT WORK in the last 3 major versions.

Can someone please either explain how to make it work, or explain why I'm wrong and I shouldn't expect it to work (eg, there is a more modern method of connecting a database to a ListBox than TableAdapters and Data Binding).

Edit: To reproduce: Create a WinForms project targeting .NET 6+. Add a dataset. Add a form. On the form, add a combobox. On the combobox, attempt to add databindings.

Comment: Does this help? [Data binding overview (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview?view=netdesktop-7.0)

Comment: No, because VS basically crashes when I attempt to apply a binding source via the UI.  Please see the linked question for more details on the problem.

Comment: I think this question needs more debugging details and (ideally) a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For what it's worth using Net framework for winforms is not absurd - its a mature framework for winform development that is fully supported by Microsoft and if not cutting edge is still in many cases is a good choice, whereas Net Core winforms tools is, well, not so much (but opinions will vary - I personally have hedged my bets on it so far but look forward to more improvements with the .Net 8 release).

Comment: No actual code is necessary for a MRE, nor is there deugging info to provide - this is an issue with the IDE.  However, I have added the steps necessary to experience the issues for oneself.